# Heroku doesn't load js (only css) files to production but locally it works

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, heroku

I couldn't find the correct answer to my issue so I have to ask you guys.
I am developing my node (express) app to Heroku, but production build of Heroku takes only CSS files from my public folder. However, when I type:

```
heroku local web
```

in my terminal, everything works fine. Here is my server.ts file to include public assets:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));
```

and this is my folder structure:

```
-root
   server.ts
   -public
      css/
      js/
```

If I check "Sources" in production Heroku app I see that CSS folder is included but not js.

Thanks

Comment: Does it give a warning on the url bar saying page is trying to load unsafe scripts?

Comment: Nope, just failed to load :( 
after trying: Heroku logs in the terminal, I can see these js files with status 200

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was related to mine .gitignore file where this public/js was included.